# Retrofit boolean or array in json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

i have one problem with my feed..

Sometimes is:

```
"logo": {
           "logo": "56ab76c2d98028.97224188_logo.png",
           "logo_thumbnail": "56ab76c2d98028.97224188_logo_thumbnail.png"
      }
```

And sometime is:

```
"logo": false
```

My retrofit object is:

```
public class EventsItem 
{         
    public LogoObject logo = new LogoObject();        
}
```

And LogoObject is:

```
 public class LogoObject {

    private String logo;
    private String logo_thumbnail;

    public String getLogo()
    {
        return (!Helper.isStringEmpty(logo)) ? logo : logo_thumbnail;
    }
}
```

If logo is false then retrofit says error

Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 51 path $.logo

Thanks for answers..

Comment: are you the developer of server side too? if so change it to return `{"logo": null}` ... or even let `EventsItem` object have no such field if there is no logo ... as different type for the same property is not a good solution

Comment: i think you need to use Converter to do so. Their you can check which type of JSON you got.

Comment: No, i do not server side developer :( i will not change this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own converter, or perhaps write a custom deserializer.

Look it up, here is an example:

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Or you can try to use `Object` and check the type:

```
if (obj instanceof Boolean)
```